# json loop through though nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this json result:

```
{"Search":[
  {"Title":"Batman Begins","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0372784","Type":"movie","Poster":"N/A"},
  {"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt2975590","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman","Year":"1989","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODM2OTc0Njg2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA4NjQxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman Forever","Year":"1995","imdbID":"tt0112462","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNWY3M2I0YzItNzA1ZS00MzE3LThlYTEtMTg2YjNiOTYzODQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman & Robin","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0118688","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: The Animated Series","Year":"1992–1995","imdbID":"tt0103359","Type":"series","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3MjcwNzY3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzA2MTI5._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: Under the Red Hood","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1569923","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNDEyMjExOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzU4MDU0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt2313197","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 2","Year":"2013","imdbID":"tt2166834","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1Mjk1NTY2NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTA2MDEwNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],
  "totalResults":"312",
  "Response":"True"
}
```

I'm trying to loop through the array and post each "movie" into separate div block, I can't seem to retrieve the information correctly from the array...

I tried this code and it works fine when using javascript alert()... but as soon as I want to .text() the information I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object...`

Here is the code that works with the alert, but not for .text()

```
$.ajax(search_sUrl, {
    complete: function(p_oXHR, p_sStatus){
        oData_search = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);

        for(var i = 0; i <= oData_search.totalResults; i++) {
            alert(oData_search["Search"][i].Title);       
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add how are you using `text()`

Comment: `i <=` should be `i <` if `.totalResults` represents the typical `.length` of an Array.

Comment: for example `$movie_container.find('.movie_block').text(oData_search["Search"][i].Title);`

Comment: as pointed out you are going past end of array , last iteration would throw that error

Comment: Use `console.log` and not `alert` or `text()` to debug. You'll get more details on what's going wrong where. Aka, you'd see that error after everything logs, meaning it's iterating past where it should end.

Comment: Does `oData_search.totalResults` really equal the array length `oData_search.Search.length`?

Comment: @AlexandruVlas - that's what got me wondering - the error you're referencing means that you're trying to do `undefined.function`, (maybe you've got `text(title).doingsomethingtostringhere`? This would explain going out of bonds with array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `oData_search.Search.length` to get the array size
2. use `i < oData_search.Search.length` instead of `<=`

```js
var oData_search = {
  "Search": [{
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "Year": "2005",
    "imdbID": "tt0372784",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "N/A"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice",
    "Year": "2016",
    "imdbID": "tt2975590",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman",
    "Year": "1989",
    "imdbID": "tt0096895",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman Returns",
    "Year": "1992",
    "imdbID": "tt0103776",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODM2OTc0Njg2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA4NjQxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman Forever",
    "Year": "1995",
    "imdbID": "tt0112462",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNWY3M2I0YzItNzA1ZS00MzE3LThlYTEtMTg2YjNiOTYzODQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman & Robin",
    "Year": "1997",
    "imdbID": "tt0118688",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman: The Animated Series",
    "Year": "1992–1995",
    "imdbID": "tt0103359",
    "Type": "series",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3MjcwNzY3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzA2MTI5._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman: Under the Red Hood",
    "Year": "2010",
    "imdbID": "tt1569923",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNDEyMjExOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzU4MDU0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1",
    "Year": "2012",
    "imdbID": "tt2313197",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 2",
    "Year": "2013",
    "imdbID": "tt2166834",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1Mjk1NTY2NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTA2MDEwNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }],
  "totalResults": "312",
  "Response": "True"
}

for (var i = 0; i < oData_search.Search.length; i++) {
  var movie = oData_search.Search[i];
  $('#results').append('<div>' + movie.Title + ' - ' + movie.Year + '</div>')
}
```

```css
#results div {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. any ideas how I can create a "div" inside the for loop and wrap each movie inside that div?

Comment: I've added a simple example for creating `divs` as result. Could be somehow like this. @AlexandruVlas

Answer (score 1):

That's because your loop runs 312 times, but your object only contains a few items. When your loop runs over the actual length of items, `oData_search["Search"][i]` will be `undefined` thus the error "undefined is not an object".

Check against the array length instead.

```
for(var i = 0; i < oData_search.Search.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this  :

```
 for(var i = 0; i < oData_search["Search"].length; i++) {
            var title = oData_search["Search"][i].Title    
   }
```

value of `totalResults` is 312 , but elements in `oData_search["Search"]` are 8 .

Answer (score 1):

Because *oData_search.Search* is an array instead of the classical for loop you may use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). In this way you avoid to get elements not available in the array itself:

A little example:

```js
var str = '{"Search":[\
{"Title":"Batman Begins","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0372784","Type":"movie","Poster":"N/A"},\
{"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt2975590","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},\
{"Title":"Batman","Year":"1989","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODM2OTc0Njg2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA4NjQxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},\
{"Title":"Batman Forever","Year":"1995","imdbID":"tt0112462","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNWY3M2I0YzItNzA1ZS00MzE3LThlYTEtMTg2YjNiOTYzODQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman & Robin","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0118688","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},\
{"Title":"Batman: The Animated Series","Year":"1992–1995","imdbID":"tt0103359","Type":"series","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3MjcwNzY3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzA2MTI5._V1_SX300.jpg"},\
{"Title":"Batman: Under the Red Hood","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1569923","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNDEyMjExOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzU4MDU0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},\
{"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt2313197","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},\
{"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 2","Year":"2013","imdbID":"tt2166834","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1Mjk1NTY2NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTA2MDEwNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],\
"totalResults":"312",\
"Response":"True"\
}';

oData_search = $.parseJSON(str);
oData_search.Search.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
  console.log(ele.Title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
oData_search = {"Search":[
  {"Title":"Batman Begins","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0372784","Type":"movie","Poster":"N/A"},
  {"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt2975590","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman","Year":"1989","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODM2OTc0Njg2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA4NjQxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman Forever","Year":"1995","imdbID":"tt0112462","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNWY3M2I0YzItNzA1ZS00MzE3LThlYTEtMTg2YjNiOTYzODQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman & Robin","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0118688","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: The Animated Series","Year":"1992–1995","imdbID":"tt0103359","Type":"series","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3MjcwNzY3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzA2MTI5._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: Under the Red Hood","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1569923","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNDEyMjExOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzU4MDU0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt2313197","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},
  {"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 2","Year":"2013","imdbID":"tt2166834","Type":"movie","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1Mjk1NTY2NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTA2MDEwNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],
  "totalResults":"312",
  "Response":"True"
}
oData_search.Search.forEach(function(value, key){
  console.log(value.Title);
});
```

[forEach()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)

```
oData_search.Search.forEach(function(value, key){
   console.log(value.Title);
});
```